# Printing the enum string values (not keys) in D

Tags: d

I print "F" not "Fahrenheit" in this code. How can I print the enum value not the key?

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    enum TemperatureUnit : string { C = "Celsius", F = "Fahrenheit" }
    writefln("%s", TemperatureUnit.F);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply cast it to a string:

```
writefln("%s", cast(string) TemperatureUnit.F);
```

Note that this cast is NOT necessary when assigning it to a string:

```
string s = TemperatureUnit.F; // just works
```

It only comes into play here because the `std.stdio.write*` family of functions, as well as `std.conv.to`, look at the exact type passed to it and try to specialize on it. When it is `enum Color { red, green, blue }`, printing out the name is useful. But that behavior is less helpful when the value is a printable string too. Casting tells the function you want it treated like a plain string rather than an enum.